# ReactiveUI Xamarin.ios bootsrapper for clean app launch

Tags: xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I have been looking for some examples on how to launch a xamarin.ios app in reactive-ui. I am also new in Xamarin.ios so maybe I am missing a crucial step. All examples I've found are either old, outdated or requires too much manual setup. I am looking to make a setup in a way where calling RoutedViewHost will resolve the UIViewController, which currently does not work and I get black screens. I assume there's no easy way to hook things up but wanted to check here first and ask the question.

Similar to how you can bootstrap a Xamarin.forms project, and how my code below successfully works in Xamarin.Forms, I'd like to start one in native.ios too.. So far I could not get the bindings and routing to work on initial app launch. I have below code in **AppDelegate**;

cs

```
var bootstrap = new AppBootstrapper(); 
var rootViewController = bootstrap.CreateMainView(); 
Window.RootViewController = rootViewController; 
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

AppBootstrapper is a ReactiveObject, IScreen object and I try to register a simple LoginView for starters to test this out. View is in Storyboard, assigned to LoginViewController.

cs

```
public class AppBootstrapper: ReactiveObject, IScreen

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        _routingState = new RoutingState();
        InitializeIoC();            
        RegisterViews();
        RegisterRoutableViewModals();

        _routingState.Navigate.Execute(new LoginViewModel(this));
```

...

```
private void InitializeIoC()
{
    Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(this, typeof(IScreen));
}

private void RegisterViews()
{
    Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new LoginViewController(), typeof(IViewFor<LoginViewModel>));
}

private void RegisterRoutableViewModals()
{
    Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new LoginViewModel(), typeof(IRoutableViewModel), typeof(LoginViewModel).FullName);
}

public UIViewController CreateMainView()
{
    return new RoutedViewHost();
}
```

...

```
public partial class LoginViewController : ReactiveViewController<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginViewController()
        {
            ViewModel = new LoginViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
            {
                this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.btnLogin)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Username, x => x.txtPassword.Text)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Password, x => x.txtPassword.Text)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Warning, x => x.lblWarning.Text)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.IsExecuteEnabled, x => x.btnLogin.Enabled)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
            });
        }
```

...

```
 public class LoginViewModel: ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        public string UrlPathSegment => "Login";

        public IScreen HostScreen { get; }

        public LoginViewModel(IScreen screen = null)
        {
            HostScreen = screen ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IScreen>();

            LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async => Login());

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Username, x => x.Password, x => x.LoginCommand,
                    (user, pass, command) =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass) &&
                        user.Length >= 3 &&
                        !IsCommandExecuting &&
                        !_disableLoginButton)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsExecuteEnabled, out _isExecuteEnabled);

            LoginCommand.IsExecuting
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsCommandExecuting, out _isCommandExecuting);
        }
```

Comment: So one thing I notice is you are passing a `ReactiveViewController` as the `RootViewController` I would think it should be the `RoutedViewHost` should be a `UINavigationController`